# Rails model .build set id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

In my app I have 3 model:

- OrganizationType
- Organization
- OrganizationTypeLink
  as you guess: my organization could perform more than one action, and this type of action's I want to link with organization...

And in controller I write so:

```
def create
    @admin_organization = Organization.new(admin_organization_params)
@admin_organization.organization_type_links.build(organization_type_id: params[:organization_type_id], organization_id: @admin_organization.id)
if @admin_organization.save
....
```

And in model OrganizationTypeLink I see new rows in db, but how to store in Organization `organization_type_link_id` ? How could I store it in db?

I am new to RoR, so please give advice )

upd:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization_type
  has_many :organization_type_links, :dependent => :destroy
end

class OrganizationTypeLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :organization_type
end

class OrganizationType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organizations
  has_many :organization_type_links
end
```

Comment: Can you share the Models of the 3 models. Also it would be great if you could share the schema.rb for them.

Answer (score 1):

> how to store in Organization organization_type_link_id ? how could i store it in db?

The way you have currently defined associations in these 3 models: `OrganizationType, Organization and OrganizationTypeLink`

`Organization has_many organization_type_links` means that OrganizationTypeLink will have a foreign key named `organization_id` in it **and not the other way round.**

*If you want to have `organization_type_link_id` in Organization then you would need to setup association as:*

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization_type
  belong_to :organization_type_link
end

class OrganizationTypeLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organizations, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :organization_type
end
```

Comment: no.... OrganizationTypeLink is a linking table no has_many there! also your answer didn't contain how and what to write in controller

Comment: Organization could have one or more types, not type could contain org-s

Comment: @brabertaser1992 Kirti's answer is correct as far as the way your question is currently written. The main point she is making is that what you are asking doesn't make sense in the way you have your models set up. In essence, there is no such field *anywhere, in any model* called `organization_type_link_id`. The only way to have such a field (I assume in `Organization`) is to flip the relationship around, as Kirti pointed out. That's why no answer can be given containing controller code; it is not possible given the model structure.

Comment: @brabertaser1992 Why don't you tell us what part you're confused or unsure about; does my explanation make any sense? Are you unsure how the `belongs_to` and `has_many` relationships work in terms of foreign key placement, etc?